# Make a simple dendrogram using hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a simple distance matrix as such:

```
I tried making my own distance matrix:

 distances=matrix(c(0,  6.32,  11.3,     1,    10,  5.66,  4.24,
           6.32,     0,  6.32,  6.08,     6,  2.83,  3.16,
           11.3,  6.32,     0,  10.6,     2,  5.66,  7.07,
           1,  6.08,  10.6,     0,  9.22,     5,  3.61,
           10,     6,     2,  9.22,     0,  4.47,  5.83,
           5.66,  2.83,  5.66,     5,  4.47,     0,  1.41,
           4.24,  3.16,  7.07,  3.61,  5.83,  1.41,     0),nrow=7,   ncol=7, byrow = TRUE)

But this doesn't cluster

    > hc <- hclust(distances)
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I would like to create a dendrogram based on measuring the smallest distances between clusters. With the end product looking like this:

[image]

Any ideas? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input for hclust requires `a dissimilarity structure as produced by ‘dist’`, with matrix, you can convert it to a 'dist' object and then hclust and plot:

```
plot(hclust(as.dist(distances)))
```

[image]

Comment: Mr wolf need your help https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/merging-based-on-chromosome-coordinates

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks like I needed the "single" method.

Comment: maybe ```cutree(..,h=0.1)``` ? hey this is not related to the question. I suggest you post it as another question